# Navigating registry files

Tags: c#, .net, registry

I am trying to read data from the registry files of other machines.  Basically I have the hard drives of other systems, from which I can copy out, or directly read, for example, the SYSTEM file (Windows/system32/config/SYSTEM), so I can read data from the USBStor keys (and other stuff).

Please note I'm NOT trying to read .REG files that are exported from the registry, and NOT trying to read the the hives from the local machine. ;-)

I have been trying to find any type of library or native .Net way to do this, preferably for free!  There is lots of references to reading .REG files but not the "flat" files taken from other systems.

Anyone come across this before?

Comment: You may wish to look at the [remote registry service](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754820.aspx)

Comment: These systems are dead.  I have physical access to their hard drives.  I don't have access to them on a network.

Answer (score 2):

Check out `RegLoadKey()` (MSDN [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724889%28v=VS.85%29.aspx)), you should be able to do something like this:

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using Microsoft.Win32; 

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {

    [DllImport("advapi32.dll")]
    public static extern int RegLoadKey(uint hKey, string lpSubKey, string lpFile);
    [DllImport("advapi32.dll")]
    public static extern int RegUnLoadKey(uint hKey, string lpSubKey);
    [DllImport("advapi32.dll")]
    public static extern int OpenProcessToken(int ProcessHandle, int DesiredAccess, ref int tokenhandle);
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    public static extern int GetCurrentProcess();
    [DllImport("advapi32.dll")]
    public static extern int AdjustTokenPrivileges(int tokenhandle, int disableprivs, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Struct)]ref TOKEN_PRIVILEGES Newstate, int bufferlength, int PreivousState, int Returnlength);
    [DllImport("advapi32.dll")]
    public static extern int LookupPrivilegeValue(string lpsystemname, string lpname, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Struct)] ref LUID lpLuid);


    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct LUID
    {
        public int LowPart;
        public int HighPart;
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct TOKEN_PRIVILEGES
    {
        public LUID Luid;
        public int Attributes;
        public int PrivilegeCount;
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int TOKEN_ADJUST_PRIVILEGES = 0x00000020;
        int SE_PRIVILEGE_ENABLED = 0x00000002;
        int TOKEN_QUERY = 0x00000008;
        int token = 0;
        int retval = 0;
        uint HKU = 0x80000003;
        string SE_BACKUP_NAME = "SeBackupPrivilege";
        string SE_RESTORE_NAME = "SeRestorePrivilege";

        string tmpHive = "offlineSystemHive";
        string offlineHive = "E:\\Windows\\system32\\config\\SYSTEM";

        LUID RestoreLuid = new LUID();
        LUID BackupLuid = new LUID();

        TOKEN_PRIVILEGES TP = new TOKEN_PRIVILEGES();
        TOKEN_PRIVILEGES TP2 = new TOKEN_PRIVILEGES();

        retval = OpenProcessToken(GetCurrentProcess(), TOKEN_ADJUST_PRIVILEGES | TOKEN_QUERY, ref token);
        retval = LookupPrivilegeValue(null, SE_RESTORE_NAME, ref RestoreLuid);
        retval = LookupPrivilegeValue(null, SE_BACKUP_NAME, ref BackupLuid);

        TP.PrivilegeCount = 1;
        TP.Attributes = SE_PRIVILEGE_ENABLED;
        TP.Luid = RestoreLuid;
        TP2.PrivilegeCount = 1;
        TP2.Attributes = SE_PRIVILEGE_ENABLED;
        TP2.Luid = BackupLuid;

        retval = AdjustTokenPrivileges(token, 0, ref TP, 1024, 0, 0);
        retval = AdjustTokenPrivileges(token, 0, ref TP2, 1024, 0, 0);

        int rtnVal = RegLoadKey(HKU, tmpHive, offlineHive);
        Console.WriteLine(rtnVal); //should be 0

        RegistryKey baseKey = Registry.Users.OpenSubKey("offlineSystemHive\\ControlSet001\\Control\\ComputerName\\ComputerName");
        Console.WriteLine(baseKey.GetValue("ComputerName"));
        baseKey.Close();

        rtnVal = RegUnLoadKey(HKU, tmpHive);
        Console.WriteLine(rtnVal); //should be 0
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Raney,  Sorry for the delay in getting back:  No... I can't seem to get it to work.  The above code runs without a hitch, but when I create the "baseKey", it is null.  No error is thrown when calling RegLoadKey.  Your method is exactly what I am trying to achieve though.

Comment: RegLoadKey is returning "1314" which is a permissions issue ?  I have confirmed I have taken ownership of the windows directory and I am running my app with admin privledges.  Thoughts?

Comment: Alright, this got _real_ complicated... much credit goes to this thread: [http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowssdk/thread/5c623051-e3ed-4e12-bcdc-e74de0500e6e](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowssdk/thread/5c623051-e3ed-4e12-bcdc-e74de0500e6e). I updated the above code. It mounts to HKEY_USERS\offlineSystemHive, but it works. In short, you have to adjust the token privileges for your process, before mounting.

Comment: Well, sorry, but this still doesn't work.  I can tell you that retval = 1 after calling "OpenProcessToken"  and "LookupPrivilegeValue", as well as "AdjustTokenPrivileges".  I can confirm that my process as running as an administrator (with new WindowsPrincipal(WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent()).IsInRole(WindowsBuiltInRole.Administrator)).  I have taken ownership and granted full permissions for my user and the administrators group on my local system.  I am trying to load a hive from a XP Pro system into my Win 7 x64 system.

Comment: I am able to do this manually with no issues by using RegEdit.exe and just loading the XP SYSTEM file into my HKey_Local_Machine.  Thanks a million for your efforts.

Comment: I'm testing all this on XP x64 at home; let me see what it does on W7 x64 when I get into work tomorrow.

Comment: Slightly modified the above code again - "SYSTEM" isn't necessary in the open key path, and a Close() is necessary for the hive to be unmountable. Working great on Win7. Are you running as administrator, with UAC disabled?

Comment: Sorry.  rtnVal still 1314.  I have disabled UAC and yes I am logged on as administrator and running the app w/ administrator privileges.

Comment: What else do you have in your code? I decided to build out a utility based on this today, and after I'd added five or six readouts to my Main function it started throwing 1314 out of no where. Scaled back one line and back to 0 / 0 successes. I ended up creating an openKey() method and moving my FileVersionInfo reports to another class. It seems to be extremely touchy, and I'm not sure why - play with your source, move things around, isolate as much as you can.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `RegistryKey.OpenRemoteBaseKey` method explained [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8zha3xws.aspx). Note that according to the linked msdn documentation:

> In order for a key to be opened remotely, both the server and client
>   machines must be running the remote registry service, and have remote
>   administration enabled.

To enable the remote registry service, use the link Blorgbeard mentioned in the comment: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754820.aspx

Here is a sample:

```
      RegistryKey FetchedRemoteMachineKey;

 FetchedRemoteMachineKey = RegistryKey.OpenRemoteBaseKey(
                           RegistryHive.CurrentUser, RemoteMachineName).OpenSubKey(
                           "Machine");
```

Comment: Sorry, again, these systems are not on a network.  I have physical access to the hard drives and their files.